# Layout making multiple columns scrollable? CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styles, antd

I have the following layout:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-header-antd483-forked-ub5tm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

With a fixed header and content container with height of 100vh - header height. Within content I have two columns, I would like to make them scrollable when its greater than its container.

How can I add scrollbars to each column within their fixed height?

```
 <Layout>
    <Header style={{ position: "fixed", zIndex: 1, width: "100%" }}></Header>
    <Content
      style={{
        marginTop: 64,
        paddingTop: 8,
        height: "calc(100vh - 64px)",
        width: "100%"
      }}
    >
      <Row>
        <Col style={{ overflowY: "scroll" }} lg={6} md={9} sm={23} xs={23}>
          <Card>hello World</Card>
          <Card>hello World</Card>
          <Card>hello World</Card>
          <Card>hello World</Card>
          <Card>hello World</Card>
          <Card>hello World</Card>
          <Card>hello World</Card>
        </Col>
        <Col lg={18} md={16}>
          <Card
            style={{
              height: "calc(100vh - 64px)"
            }}
          >
            //super long text content
            ...
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Content>
  </Layout>
```

Comment: you need to link boostrap too i guess ? and also reset a few CSS rules (unless there's build-in class i do not know of) . possible example : https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-header-antd483-forked-mi4wm?file=/index.css:300-529

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you do with your code, but you make it way to complicated. I simplified your code to achieve what you want.

To achieve the wanted design I used a css-grid.

the grid has 2 rows, 1 for the header and one for the content. The header row height is defined as `min-content` which will ensure that it adepts to the height that is needed to stay responsive. The min height for the header itself is set to your `64px`. However, if for some reason more space is needed, then it will adjust accordingly.

Then the second row is for the content. Its height is set to `auto`. The entire grid height is set to `100vh`. therefor `auto` will fill all remaining space without needing to use the `css calc function`.

The second row also has the `overflow-y` set to `auto`. If the content is higher then the container, a scrollbar will appear.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

body div {
  padding: 5px;
}

#header {
  grid-column: span 2;
  min-height: 64px;
}

#col-left,
#col-right {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="col-left">
    <Card>hello World</Card>
    <Card>hello World</Card>
    <Card>hello World</Card>
    <Card>hello World</Card>
    <Card>hello World</Card>
    <Card>hello World</Card>
    <Card>hello World</Card>
  </div>
  <div id="col-right">
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
    <p>super long text</p>
  </div>
<body>
```